# Npm not being able to find a file - Installing bcrypt

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, bcrypt

I'm having an issue with installing Bcrypt via NPM.

Installing it using the command `npm install bcrypt` gives the following:

```
npm WARN lifecycle npm is using /opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> bcrypt@3.0.6 install /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/package.json'
npm WARN mydomain No description
npm WARN mydomain No repository field.
npm WARN mydomain No README data
npm WARN mydomain No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-042stab140.1
npm ERR! argv "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node" "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have run `npm bugs bcrypt` and my server has also spit out the following:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-042stab140.1
npm ERR! argv "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node" "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm" "bugs" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! path xdg-open
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn xdg-open

npm ERR! enoent spawn xdg-open ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent spawn xdg-open ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Any ideas as to what's going on? Is there a compatibility issue to the version of NPM or Node that I'm running?

Any help is appreciated :)

Cheers

Comment: Yes, it says the latest version of bcrypt is not compatible with your npm version

Comment: Can you recommend an alternative to bcrypt?